# geom_text how to display no decimals when rounded to nearest thousands using scale=1e-3

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, geom-bar

My code is as below:

```
ggplot(ctd_monthly_num_rides,
       aes(x=factor(month,level=
                      c('January','February','March',
                        'April', 'May','June',
                        'July','August','September',
                        'October','November','December')),
           y=number_of_rides,
           fill=member_casual)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity',width=.65,position='dodge') +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=label_number(suffix = 'K', scale = 1e-3)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=label_number(scale=1e-3,suffix='K')(number_of_rides)),
            position=position_dodge(width=0.5),vjust=-0.25,size=3.25) +
  labs(title='Number of Rides by Each User Type & Day of Week',
       fill='User Type') +
  xlab('') +
  ylab('Number of Rides')
```

This generates the following visual:
[image]

I don't wish to display the decimals after rounding it since it looks a little difficult to look and follow the chart. I simply want it to show 442.06K to 442K, for example. I tried messing with `digits=` but that doesn't seem to help much...

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
  geom_text(
      aes(label= paste0(round(number_of_rides,0),"K")),
      position=position_dodge(width=0.5),
      vjust=-0.25,
      size=3.25)
```

Comment: Hello, this does remove the decimal but doesn't cut the large numbers down to thousands and shows numbers like 273045K, 210550K instead of 273K, 210K as I had hoped for, presumably because it removed `label_number()`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is to use `number` from `scales` package

```
paste0(scales::number(442.06), 'K')
```

Comment: Hi, I'm assuming that this rounds just a single value? If not, where should I include this in my code?

Comment: @LordPuggo I am unable to test this as you have not provided snapshot of the data, I suggest to try  `geom_text(aes(label=paste0(scales::number(number_of_rides, big.mark =''), 'K')), position=position_dodge(width=0.5),vjust=-0.25,size=3.25)`. Here is an example `paste0(scales::number(c(44.95, 343.3434, 434.5533, 3434.6346), big.mark = ""), 'K')` and output is "45K"   "343K"  "435K"  "3435K".

Comment: From you comments on Luca's post, I reckon you are looking for something like this, for example, 
`nums = c(44.9500,     343.3434,   44334.5533, 3434437.6346)
paste0(ifelse(nchar( trunc( abs(nums) ) ) > 3, scales::number(nums, accuracy = 1, big.mark = '', scale = 1e-3), scales::number(nums,  big.mark = '')), 'K')`, please let me know if this helps?